# How to get unique users in a given period of time in Google Analytics through API?

Tags: google-analytics-api

How do I get unique users in a given period of time in Google Analytics through API?
For example, I want to get unique users from 2022-10-01 to 2022-10-12.
I know there's a feature called 30 Day Active Users in GA, but it is impossible to calculate only for the given period (12 days, not 30 days)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dataRange` attribute with metrics and dimensions to filter the specific date visitors

For example

```
 'json' => [
           'reportRequests' => [
                'viewId' => "viewId",
                'dateRanges' => [
                    "startDate" => "2022-10-01",
                    "endDate" => "2022-10-12"
                   ],
                'dimensions' => ['name' => 'ga:date'],
                'metrics' => ['expression' => 'ga:visitors'],
                ]
            ]
```

To find more about metrics and dimensions refer this https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/dimensions-metrics-explorer/